# Avoid deep grid search

Tags: regression, optimization

The question is basically on the Title, but I will provide more details:

## How avoid several loops in a hyperparameter grid search in order to save time?

I'm developing on matlab a Regression with the following pseudocode:

```
# Training and test spliting (Fictitious function)
train , test = train_test_split(data)

# Perform grid search, leave one out and optimization to make a regression in order to append the MSE and MAE in a table

for param1 = [0:1:10]
   for param2 = [0:1:10]
     for param3 = [0:1:10]
        for regressor in regressors
           # make some matricial operations and leave one out

           #  perform with CVX to solve a convex optimization problem with the 3 parameters of the 3 loops iteration
           # make predictions and store them

# compute MAE and MSE to append it to a matrix and compare the error measures to check which combination of parameters perform better
```

At the end this works, but, the more combinations the longer the process takes...

## Target

I would like to perform a method in order to avoid doing thousands of combinations and find in an efficient way these parameters without going through all of them.

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask any.

Comment: I was editing the question, now it is finished, @Tim , I would thank people to not to downvote this question. which took me 30 min to write... Please be honest and consider the effort of people spending their time!

Comment: Downvoting doesn't take into account the amount of time you spent on a question or an answer, it just judges the relevence of it. Your question might have been judged too broad for this forumas hyperparameter tuning is a whole field of research. (It is not me who downvoted though)

Comment: deep = massive , grid search is defined by @ysearka properly.  The relevance of the question is something subjective, because of that this is a forum, respect people....

Comment: @PeCa it was not me who downvoted. People usually downvote if they feel that some question is low quality, or doesn't deserve attention. In the future, if you don't want your questions to be downvoted, it is a good strategy to try to post your question as a high-quality from the beginning, so it does not need further editing. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to show the formulas of the scientific paper I'm writing because of that I wrote such "general" and "broad" question, just sensitive content. thanks for the information @Tim

Comment: Btw, if you want some friendly introduction to optimization, you can check: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319082622 (it is very introductory and informal, but should be a friendly starting point)

Comment: I feel the urge of precising what I meant by "relevance", this is not a question of whether it's a "good" or "bad" question, but rather whether it fits the requirements of the forum, ie if it doesn't belong in another stackexchange environment, if the question is clear enough etc... As described in @Tim 's links. I wouldn't dare judging a question about its "smartness"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid search is a method for hyperparameters optimization amongst others. It tends to be well known as it doesn't depend on much hypotheses. For instance if you use a gradient descent method with a cost function that isn't strictly convex you might end up in a local minimum, which shouldn't happen in a grid search.

Nonetheless, depending on your model (and on your cost function) you can use other methods such as the [bayesian optimization](http://medal-lab.org/hboa/boa.pdf), or [hyper-gradient-descent](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/maclaurin15.pdf).

There are many ways to perform hyperparameter tuning. Take care though about overfitting since if you perform a huge grid search for instance you might end up on hyperparameters that fit a lot your training set without being as good on test sets.

For a linear regression though you probably won't need to tune your hyperparameters, you'd better search for an approximate of the inverse of the matrix containing your coefficients.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if you have to perform a grid search, try to do it with a higher stepsize first and then zoom upon the region of the hyperparameters space where you performed best. It will save you a fine amount of time and computation!

Comment: Your'e answering what I was expecting for... this is something to start studying it, thanks a lot :)